# Create a dynamic expression using parameters in Reporting Services 2008 R2

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I need to create a dynamic expression on a SSRS 2008 R2 report.

I have a table with those columns: 
ID, NumericField1, NumericField2, NumericField3
and a parameter named FormulaParameter.

On the report I need to create another column based on an dynamic expression written on a parameter. In the `FormulaParameter` I would like to write "NumericField1 / NumericField2" or "NumericField2 * NumericField1", and the formula must be evaluated on the new column.

On this new column I simply add the expression `=Parameters!FormulaParameter.Value` but it always evaluate as a string, I need to evaluate the formula inside the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Report parameters are evaluated BEFORE the report body is generated, so what you are trying to do will not work. 
However you can do this by putting logic in the new column that will run the different formula depending on what is selected in the parameter, e.g.

```
=Iif(
     Parameters!FormulaParameter.Value = "NumericField1/NumericField2",        
     Fields!NumericField1.Value /  Fields!NumericField2.Value,    
     Iif(
        Parameters!FormulaParameter.Value = "NumericField1*NumericField2",       
        Fields!NumericField1.Value * Fields!NumericField2.Value, 
        ""
        )
  )
```

From your question it's not clear whether these formulas are the only two options or the user will be able to type in a formula of their choice. The above assumes there are a fixed set set of forumla options.

Comment: The set of options is dynamic, not fixed.